# NPM Package Development - How can i execute the build command after package install?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

how do i to generate the build folder after my package be installed?

i did this:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "babel ./src --out-dir ./build"
  }
```

But when other user install the package the npm not build.

How can i execute the build command after install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use "postinstall" in scripts.

source: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

Answer (score 1):

It's almost certainly best not to have a post-install step at all. What you really want to do is to build the project *before it is published*, and then publish the built version to NPM (assuming that's what you are trying to do). In that case, you might use a [`prepublish`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#common-uses) script:

```
// package.json

"scripts": {
  "build": "babel src -d build",
  "prepublish": "npm run build"
}
```

And make sure the *built* files are included in your [files array](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files):

```
// package.json

"files": ["build"]
```

Or that your source files are excluded in your [`.npmignore`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package):

```
// .npmignore

/src/
```

If you really do need a post-install step for some reason, use a `postinstall` script:

```
// package.json

"scripts": {
  "build": "babel src -d build",
  "postinstall": "npm run build"
}
```

But I can't think of a use-case where this would be a good idea.